# Is it possible to project query builder results into a function call, inside an eloquent query builder context

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

An employee has many employeeareas, I need to check which employees have any employee areas that are within 12km of any points in the $latLngCol collection.

I need to know if I am trying to do something that's possible with eloquent or if I should be looking at DB raw queries and stored procedures/MySQL functions.

As you can see I am calling a function LatLngToLatLng() and trying to pass/project the results of a query into it.

```
$employees = Employee::whereHas('employeeareas',function($query) use($latLngCol) {

    $query->where(function($ca) use($latLngCol)  { 

        $latLngCol->first(function($key, $val) use($ca) {

            $m = DistanceCalculator::LatLngToLatLng($val['lat'],$val['lng'],$ca->select('latitude')->first(), $ca->select('longitude')->first());

            if($m <= 12000) return true;


        });  

    }

    )->first();
});
```

In .NET, with Entity framework it would look like this:

```
var employees =
employee.where(e => e.employeeareas
.first(ea => LatLngList
.first(p => calculateDistance(ea.lat, ea.lng, p.lat, p.lng))
)).toList;
```

I need to know if I can write something similar with eloquent without having to resort to RAW queries.

Comment: Since you have to calculate the distance based on the lat and lang you could pull all the results and use the **filter()** method on the collection to remove the records based on the calculated distance https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter

Answer (score 0):

you can't  write like .net with eloquent.

but Laravel provide collection class .
you can use filter method in collection for filter the collection by the given callback.

example if you have a collection named `$collection` then you can filter it with a function like this

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});

$filtered->all();
```

since your query is complex it better to use your way of code.it would be messy if you collection for your problem